# Attributive nouns in science

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns, attributive-adjectives

I see more and more articles in scientific journals, where attributive nouns use plural. To me they sound really strange and non-intuitive.

'materials science'
'materials design'

To me they should be 'material science' in general terms. Is there a rule for this?

Comment: It's the science of materials in general, not a particular one. Also, _material_ can be an adjective (having a physical existence), which is not the intended meaning here.

Comment: You'll find that both 'materials science' and 'material science' are in common use if you check Google ngrams or a raw Google search. The ngrams show the plural-form attributive being twice as popular as the singular form. But you are right: singular-form attributive nouns are the norm. There are obvious exceptions such as sports car, sports hall, systems analyst, often emphasising a plural aspect. But the rule is: _Check_ individual cases.